# Prove that every linear map from ${F^{n,1}}$ to ${F^{m,1}}$ is given by a matrix multiplication.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

this is my problem with it's answer but I can't understand it. I will be thankful if some one explain why it's true.(I don't know why yellow part is right and the rest).
[image]

Comment: The yellow part does not affirm anything. How can you not be sure if it is right? Question: What part do you not understand exactly? From what moment did you get lost?

Comment: yellow part says it has this obvious basis but why just one 1 entery?

Comment: He refers to the basis: $$\left. \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \dots, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\} \textrm{$m$ or $n$ rows}$$

Comment: It's obvious maybe.I'm sorry but why only one 1 entry?

Comment: For example, for $$B = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_n \end{pmatrix} \in \operatorname{Mat}(n,1,\mathbf F)$$ we have $$B = b_1\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + b_2\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \cdots + b_n\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ and then $\mathcal{M}(B) = B$. This wouldn't be that easy if the basis elements were different.

Comment: thank you so much.that was exactly my problem

Comment: @azif00 I have also other question it is for all linear maps T, how can we say it works for all linear maps with any basis?

Comment: You end up with $TB=AB$, and this conclusion doesn't depend on the choice of the basis. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @azif00 could you please explain the part which we choose basis, and how we make matrix A?